# How to transform rows of specific ID that has name + value as columns into columns of these rows names combined for that unique ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I've been stuck on this problem a while although I tried a lot of things:

So I have a table like this:

```
model | type | serialNumber | revisionNumber | value | name 
-----------------------------------------------------------

A | T1 | 2199 | 5 | 17 | sensitivity    
A | T1 | 2199 | 5 | > 100 | resistance  
A | T1 | 2199 | 5 | 19-04-2016 | calibration    
A | T1 | 2199 | 5 | 17 | sensitivity

B  | T1 | 2500 | 5 | 17 | sensitivity
```

(which is very strange I know, but just working on the DB not designed it)

Now the problem is that I want to select items which have a certain MODEL, TYPE and have a CALIBRATION DATE between two dates. At the same time I want to result of the query to show me the values of the attributes sensitivity and calibration (and even more attributes later on) and get the results of the query in the form:

```
model | type | serialNumber | revisionNumber | sensitivity | resistance | ...
```

where a `revisionNumber` and `serialNumber` uniquely define a model and type

I tried working with ROW_NUMBERS and the PARTITION BY function to give the three attributes an unique ID and then use an alias to put them in a column. But the problem is that I don't know how assign an ALIAS based on the criterium that ID of the three attributes is the same. Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `PARTITION BY`?  Are you sure you're using MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
    [model], [type], serialNumber, revisionNumber
    min(case when [name] = 'sensitivity' then [value] end) as sensitivity,
    min(case when [name] = 'resistance'  then [value] end) as resistance
from T        
group by [model], [type], serialNumber, revisionNumber
having count(
           case when [name] = 'calibration' then
               case when convert(date, [value], 105) between @start and @end then 1 end
           end
       ) > 0
```

I'm assuming SQL Server so substitute the brackets with whatever is appropriate for your platform. I believe the nested `case` will defer attempts to cast date values without causing errors.

Answer (score 0):

On SQL Server you can use PIVOT to achieve what you want:

```
SELECT P.model,P.type,P.serialNumber,P.revisionNumber,
       P.sensitivity,P.resistance,P.calibration
FROM models D
     PIVOT (MIN(D.value) FOR D.name IN (sensitivity,resistance,calibration)) AS P
```

Basically, inside the PIVOT clause you specify that you want to take the value column and spread it across sensitivity, resistance and calibration columns.

The output generated is shown below:

```
model | type | serialNumber | revisionNumber | sensitivity | resistance | calibration
A | T1 | 2199 | 5 | 17 | > 100 | 19-04-2016
B | T1 | 2500 | 5 | 17 | null | null
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but it returns three rows per model | type | serialNumber | revisionNumber with sensitivity and calibration always NULL

Comment: I have just edited my answer, I pasted the output of the query. In my opinion it is exactly what you need.

Comment: I don't get why but this doesn't seem to work on my part. I still get two rows per set of `model | serialNumber | revisionNumber` (left out the type for a moment) and only the sensitivity term returns non-NULL values

`model | serialNumber | revisionNumber | sensitivity calibration
 A    | 2199 | 5 | 17.466 | NULL
A | 2199 | 5  | NULL | NULL
A | 2199 | 6 | 17.466 | NULL`

Comment: @StijnPinson, what I see in your data is that it is different than the sample you provided here, you have A/2199/5 and A/2199/6. Because we take P.model, P.serialNumber and P.revisionNumber outside of the PIVOT clause, it will create separate rows for each combination. And I see that the sensitivity has been fetched all right for A/2199/6, probably there are no rows with calibration or resistance. If you like, you could paste somewhere a dump of your data, I will look into it.